# Get Dynamic PIVOT result executed with in EXEC() to a varchar variable

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, exec

Below code creates a `JSON` output.

> Note that : The values inside `#Person` table are generating dynamically. Once I call the stored proc which contains the below code segment, the C# code identifies the output as a `JSON` eventhough it looks like a `VARCHAR`.I need the output JSON to be a `string(VARCHAR)` since the C# model cannot be generated dynamically based on the values returned by `#Names`.

```
DROP TABLE #Names
DROP TABLE #PersonInfo    

CREATE TABLE #Names (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #PersonInfo (ID INT,NameID INT,Subject VARCHAR(100),Marks INT)

INSERT INTO #Names VALUES (1,'Paul');
INSERT INTO #Names VALUES (2,'John');
INSERT INTO #Names VALUES (3,'Tayler');

INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (1,1,'Maths',95);
INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (2,2,'Science',32);
INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (3,3,'History',23);
INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (4,2,'Maths',32);
INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (5,3,'Science',60);
INSERT INTO #PersonInfo VALUES (6,1,'Music',60);

DECLARE @DynamicCols NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @DynamicCols +=  ', SUM(' +QUOTENAME([Name])+') AS '+[Name] FROM #Names;
SET @DynamicCols = STUFF(@DynamicCols,1,1,'')
SELECT @pvt +=  ', ' +QUOTENAME([Name]) FROM #Names;
SET @pvt = STUFF(@pvt,1,1,'')

EXEC ('
SELECT [Subject],' + @DynamicCols+'
FROM (SELECT [NameID], [Subject], [Marks] FROM #PersonInfo) a
INNER JOIN #Names b ON a.NameID = b.ID
PIVOT 
(
  SUM([Marks])
  FOR [Name] IN ('+ @pvt+')
)   PIV
GROUP BY [Subject] FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES');
```

Result

`[{"Subject":"History","Paul":null,"John":null,"Tayler":23},{"Subject":"Maths","Paul":95,"John":32,"Tayler":null},{"Subject":"Music","Paul":60,"John":null,"Tayler":null},{"Subject":"Science","Paul":null,"John":32,"Tayler":60}]`

C# Code in the DAL Layer

```
public string GetMarks(string partyRoleIdList)
  {
   return _context.Query<string>(usp_GetMarks, new { IdList }).SingleOrDefault();
  }
```

**Is there a way to convert the executed value (`EXEC()`) to a `VARCHAR(MAX)` ??**

Comment: Just confirming, what about this code doesn't work currently? My understanding is the output of FOR JSON is a nvarchar(max) type so I would have thought that is already basically what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily test that the result of `FOR JSON` is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` string:

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
    VALUES(''[a'')
) DS(col)
FOR JSON AUTO
';
```

Yields this:

```
is_hidden   column_ordinal  name    is_nullable system_type_id  system_type_name    max_length  precision   scale   collation_name
0   1   JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B   1   231 nvarchar(max)   -1  0   0   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And it is string, so you can cast it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or something else easily:

```
EXEC ('
SELECT CAST(
(
SELECT [Subject],' + @DynamicCols+'
FROM (SELECT [NameID], [Subject], [Marks] FROM #PersonInfo) a
INNER JOIN #Names b ON a.NameID = b.ID
PIVOT 
(
  SUM([Marks])
  FOR [Name] IN ('+ @pvt+')
)   PIV
GROUP BY [Subject] FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)
 AS VARCHAR(400))');
```